# Why don't I change each value in the table in perl?

Tags: perl, foreach

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %table = qw/schmoe joe smith john simpson bart/; 
my $da =1;
my($key, $value); # Declare two variables at once 
while ( ($key, $value) = each(%table) ) 
{ 
    $table{$key} = ++$da;
} 

print %table;
```

the output:

```
schmoe2smith3simpson4
```

I was expecting to get to `2345...`

What is wrong with my `foreach`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the program supposed to do. And there's no foreach in the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something.

The values are changed, but when you code `print %table;`, you print keys and values.

With `Data::Dumper` module, it's more clear :

```
$ Perl
Perl Console 0.4
Perl> use Data::Dumper
Perl> my %table = qw/schmoe joe smith john simpson bart/; 
6

Perl> my $da =1;
1

Perl> my($key, $value);
2

Perl> while ( ($key, $value) = each(%table) ) { $table{$key} = ++$da; }
0

Perl> print Dumper \%table
$VAR1 = {
          'schmoe' => 2,
          'smith' => 3,
          'simpson' => 4
        };
1

Perl> print %table;
schmoe2smith3simpson41
```

If you want to iterate through the hash, you can do :

```
while(my($key, $value) = each %table) {
    print "$key=$value\n";
}
```

but the hash name is confusing, it's not a table but a *hash*.

Another solution to iterate through the hash :

```
foreach my $key (keys %table) {
    print "$key=$table{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are changing only the value and not even the key of the hash ...

If you want to change the key and the value, you can do something like :

```
while ( ($key, $value) = each(%table) ) 
{ 
    #Remove the previous key
    delete($table{$key});
    #Insert a key and a value (the same)
    $table{++$da} = $da;
}
```

But i think that it haven't much sense ...

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to change the *values* of the hash, regardless of the key (a somewhat meaningless exercise, since keys come in semi-random order), you can simply do:

```
for my $value (values %table) {
    $value = ++$da;
}
```

Or in short form:

```
$_ = ++$da for values %table;
```

Then you can print the values:

```
print values %table;
```

This will effectively do the same as your loop, since even though the order of hash elements from both `keys` and `values` are semi-random, they are semi-random consistently, and in the same way as each other. I doubt this is what you are trying to do, because as I said, it is a rather pointless exercise.

When you assign to the hash:

```
my %table = qw/schmoe joe smith john simpson bart/;
```

.. then the odd elements are keys, and the even values, as if you had written:

```
            #  keys         values
my %table = ( "schmoe"  => "joe,
              "smith"   => "john",
              "simpson" => "bart" );
```

You cannot change the keys, you can only delete them and make new ones. And if you do that, your assignment is rather pointless.